PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server
I'm unable to get the site running and connect to the database. I keep getting this error whenever I do npm run dev. I have even attempted to set connect_timeout to 1 and pool_timeout to 0, pgbouncer is also set to true.
I'm using Next.js as the React Framework, Prisma as the ORM, and Vercel Postgre as the database.
.env
# Created by Vercel CLI
POSTGRES_DATABASE="verceldb"
POSTGRES_HOST="ep-shy-union-a2mpqijj-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="(password)"
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://default:(password)@ep-shy-union-a2mpqijj-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech/verceldb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=1&sslmode=require&pool_timeout=0"
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://default:(password)@ep-shy-union-a2mpqijj-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech/verceldb?sslmode=require"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://default:(password)@ep-shy-union-a2mpqijj.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech/verceldb?sslmode=require"
POSTGRES_URL_NO_SSL="postgres://default:(password)@ep-shy-union-a2mpqijj-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech/verceldb"
POSTGRES_USER="default"
GITHUB_ID='(password)'
GITHUB_SECRET='(password)'
NEXTAUTH_URL='http://localhost:3000/api/auth'
NEXTAUTH_SECRET='(password)'

package.json
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.17.0",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.9.0",
    "next": "12.0.10",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.9.1",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "prisma": "^5.17.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.5"
  }
}

index.tsx
import React from "react"
import { GetStaticProps } from "next"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Post, { PostProps } from "../components/Post"
import prisma from '../lib/prisma';

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const feed = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: { published: true },
    include: {
      author: {
        select: { name: true },
      },
    },
  });
  return {
    props: { feed },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};

type Props = {
  feed: PostProps[]
}

const Blog: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return <></>
}

export default Blog




I hope those are not your real secrets.

I'll edit the question.

That's not enough. It's still visible in the history. You should revoke all those tokens ASAP. Never trust that you can remove something from the internet; you can't.
